# Plot isn't entered in figure in loop in function

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I'm trying to write a small function which should read a matrix of doubles, make a plot for all columns separately (and display the last row as line, as this is the mean) and save the plot. 
All commands work when I tried them on the command line, but when I run them as a script it doesn't work. The plots are not entered in the figure (only ticks and labels are redrawn). When I copy the single commands in debug mode to the command line it works.

So what am I doing wrong here?

I'm loading a matrix 'corr' prior to this loop..

```
for i=1:30; % number of components
    corr_fig(i)=figure;
    hold;
    plot(corr(1:length(sub),i));
    line ([0 (length(sub))],[(corr(length(sub)+1)) (corr(length(sub)+1))], 'Color','m')
    set(gca,'XTick',[1:(length(sub))])
    set(gca,'XTickLabel',{sub{1:length(sub)}})
    title(['Correlations for',num2str(i)])
    saveas(corr_fig(i),['corrs_for_',num2str(i)],'fig');
    hold off;
    close all;
end
```

Comment: I suggest you put a break-point in your function right before this loop and step through to see what is happening.  Check that `corr` and `sub` are both definitely what you expect them to be.  Finally, `hold` by itself just flips the hold state, safer to specify `hold on` if that's what you want.

Comment: Seconding what nkjt said about checking your data. An empty plot could be a result of an empty or NaN matrix.

Comment: Thx! I have put a break point already (before and within the loop) the data is there and looks ok. Strange thing is, after having put the break point within the loop (after plot), I can enter the plot line as it is (copy paste) to the command line, and the plots looks just fine..

Comment: Could it be the problem is actually with *saving*? Have you tried manually plotting and then after a `clear all` opening it again?

Comment: Hm, yes, manually doing all the steps works. But, if I put a break point in the script after the lines, that are supposed to plot (e.g. plot(corr(1:length(sub),i));), The figure is there, but no plot.. So I personally think it's not the saving..

Comment: try adding `drawnow` in the line before the `saveas`

Answer (score 0):

Throw in a 'drawnow' command in the loop.  This flushes out the plotting buffer and forces MATLAB to create the figure, rather than trying to skip that step due to what the compiler sees happening in the loop.

For example, this:

```
for k = 1:100;

    figure()
    plot(rand(100, 1), rand(100, 1))
    close all

end
```

draws nothing (never shows a figure window), but this:

```
for k = 1:100;

    figure()
    plot(rand(100, 1), rand(100, 1))
    drawnow
    close all

end
```

does what you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers! Figured it out on my own in the end. The code is fine, well mostly. I haven't assigned a proper variable name to the matrix I handed to the function and was not calling this name in the loop corectly (MAT.corr would have been it..) Now it's working.. Stupid me! Thanks nevertheless!